# _socketobject' object has no attribute 'bing'

Tags: python

First I wanna say I am new to python I mostly use to do programming in java so forgive me if the answer is obvious but I am having the error (_socketobject' object has no attribute 'bing') when I run my script but I cant see anything wrong with it....

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import paramiko

  host_key = paramiko.RSAKey 
  (filename='/home/moonman/Desktop/test_rsa.key')


  class Server (paramiko.ServerInterface):

def __init__(self):
    self.event = threading.Event()

def check_channel_request(self, kind, chanid):
    if kind == 'session':
        return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED
    return paramiko.OPEN_FAILED_ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED

def check_auth_password(self, username, password):
    if (username == 'moonman') and (password == 'lover23567'):
        return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
    return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED

try:
     global sock
     sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     sock.bing(('192.168.1.13' , 22))
     sock.listen(1)
     print '[+] Listening for Connection ...' 


except Exception, e:
print '[-] Cant start listening ): ' + str(e)

try:
     client, addr = sock.accept()
     print '[+] Just got a reverse connection from ' + str(addr)
     t = paramiko.Transport(client)
     t.load_server_moduli()
     t.add_server_key(host_key)
     server = Server()
     t.start_server(server=server)
     global chan
     chan = t.accept(1)
     print chan.recv(1024)
     chan.send("Connection Understood! Loud and clear!!")

except:
print "[-] Connection just died"
pass
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the line hopes to `ping` the 192.168.1.13 address through the port 22. Change that line,see if it does what you want to. I've never heard of bing,related to networking.

Comment: Also please indent your code. It's Python, code literally loses meaning without indentation.

Comment: @Mikael Sorry I am new to this ): anyway I get the same error but instead it says "_socketobject' object has no attribute 'ping'"

Comment: `sock.bing(('192.168.1.13' , 22))` meaning **bind** ?

Comment: @dsgdfg Oh my god I feel like such a idiot....... Hey its 4 Am where I am and I have been programming for 3 hours so cut me some slack.....

Comment: @dsgdfg dammmnnn how did I forgot Bind. It makes even more sense than ping in that place.

Comment: @Mikael I feel so stupid I am so sorry

Comment: @gmod74 no you're not. You are a guy trying to learn. Everyone make mistakes, even more in the beginning. Stay calm and keep going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket object has no attribute as bing. I guess you meant sock.bind which binds the socket to the address you defined.
Try this:

sock.bind(('192.168.1.13' , 22))